# Why does this binary tree search take so much longer than an insertion?

Tags: algorithm, go, time-complexity, binary-tree

I'm trying to learn/understand some basic algorithms, and today I decided to write a binary tree in Go. This is what the structure looks like:

```
type Node struct {
  Value int
  Left  *Node
  Right *Node
}
```

Here's my function to check if the tree contains an int:

```
func (tree *Node) Contains(val int) bool {
  if val == tree.Value {
    return true
  } else if val > tree.Value {
    if tree.Right != nil {
      return tree.Right.Contains(val)
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } else if val < tree.Value {
    if tree.Left != nil {
      return tree.Left.Contains(val)
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } else { // huh
    return false
  }
}
```

I wrote a test function to test how long different operations on the tree take. It takes my `Insert()` function **34ms** to insert 100,000 random integers, and it takes my `Contains()` function **33ms** to check if the tree contains 100,000  random integers. If I bump the number of random integers up to 1,000,000, it takes my `Insert()` function **34ms** to run, but my `Contains()` function suddenly takes **321ms** to run.

Why does `Contains()` run time increase so drastically, while `Insert()` stays practically the same?

Comment: Where is the `insert` function?

Comment: Can you show the Benchmark function you're using?

Comment: you should wram up running 5-10 times before timing it, sometimes languages such as java (JIT) does optimization during runtime, not sure about go, but microbenchmarking is tricky.

Comment: Binary Tree is not a Binary Search Tree

Comment: From your description, I'd suspect that the tree actually contains only 100,000 integers, so it takes the same amount of time to insert. But you're doing 10 times as many queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Insert` function should periodically rebalance the tree, as an imbalanced tree may lead to very uneven traversal times.  As a result, `Insert` *should* generally be slower that `Contains`.

If your `Insert` function does not rebalance the tree, then the time required for any given function become O(n) worst case instead of O(log n) and fairly unpredictable.

In addition, when talking about O(...) time complexity, we're generally talking about *worst case* behavior.  If you time single calls, then any given call may take (much) less time than the worst case -- for example, `Contains` looking for the node that happens to be the root will return immediately regardless of the size.

Comment: In such case, `Insert` should also become `O(n)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user58697: worst-case, yes, but any given call may take less time in an unpredictable way.